# Cordova Security Alert Google Play Android

Tags: android, cordova, security

I have an app published on Google Play and I have received this warning recently:

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6325474

I have upgraded cordova version via command line and re-uploaded the apk and I still get the same warning.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: To answer my own question, I think this is what solved it. I had updated cordova but I also had to update the cordova android version as well:

cordova platform update android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not necessarily update android version explicitly. Updating Cordova version through CLI automatically updates the cordova android version as well. All you need to do is to remove android platform and add it once again after cordova update and rebuild android platform again. Hope it helps.